# How to guard all routes for deactivation [CanDeactivate]?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I would like to apply a deactivation guard for all routes and keep control at component level.

So I have this abstract class:

```
export abstract class Deactivable {
  abstract shouldDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

Here is the guard:

```
export class CanDeactivateService implements CanDeactivate<Component> {

  canDeactivate(
    component: Component, 
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if(component instanceof Deactivable) {
      return component.shouldDeactivate();
    }

    return true;
  }

}
```

and then in component I have like (observable replaced by bool for brevity):

```
export class MyComponent extends Deactivable implements... {

  ///// Deactivable
  shouldDeactivate(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  ////////
}
```

then I apply the guard to the root route, but it does not work, it seems shouldDeactivate never gets called, What's going wrong?

**Edit 1:**
In fact I found out that the guard's canDeactivate never gets called...
Might it be a bug?

**Edit 2:**
Usage:

```
const routes: Routes=[
    { path: "", canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateService], children: [
        //All routes here
    ] }
]
```

Comment: Can you add your guard usage into your question ?